# Proper gsub regular expression for this URL?

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have a string representing a URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/somepage.aspx?id=33
```

..I'd like to escape the forward slashes and the question mark:

```
http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/somepage.aspx\?id=33
```

How can I do this via gsub?  I've been playing with some regular expressions in there but haven't hit on the winning formula yet.

Comment: The `.` I'd like to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use

```
url = url.gsub(/(?=[\/?])/, '\\')
```

As shown here

```
url = 'http://www.mysite.com/somepage.aspx?id=33'
url = url.gsub(/(?=[\/?])/, '\\')
puts url
```

**output**

```
http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/somepage.aspx\?id=33
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one `result = searchText.gsub(/(\/|\?)/, "\\\\$1")`

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using a block to make it more readable:

```
url.gsub(/[\/?]/) { |c| "\\#{c}" }
```